# Combine and sum all the total_amount with same month?

Tags: mysql

I want to combine and sum all the `total_amount`, `quantity` and `total_order` with the same month.

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%b') AS Month, 
  COUNT(tbl_purchase_received_details.purchase_received_id) AS Total_Order, 
  SUM(IFNULL(tbl_purchase_received_details.received_quantity,0)) AS Quantity, 
  IFNULL((tbl_supplier_medicine.price) * 
  SUM(tbl_purchase_received_details.received_quantity),0) AS Total_Amount, 
  tbl_supplier.supplier_name AS Supplier 
 FROM 
  tbl_date 
 LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_purchase_received ON tbl_purchase_received.date_received = tbl_date.date 
 LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_purchase_received_details ON 
  tbl_purchase_received.purchase_received_id = 
  tbl_purchase_received_details.purchase_received_id 
 LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_supplier_medicine ON tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id = 
  tbl_purchase_received_details.supplier_medicine_id 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_supplier ON 
  tbl_supplier.supplier_id = tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_id 
 WHERE 
  YEAR(tbl_date.date) = YEAR(NOW()) 
 GROUP BY 
  DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%b'), 
  tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id 
 ORDER BY 
  tbl_date.date, tbl_supplier_medicine.supplier_medicine_id
```

```
Month  Total_Order  Quantity  Total_Amount  Supplier
Jan    0            0         0             NULL
Feb    0            0         0             NULL
Mar    0            0         0             NULL
Apr    0            0         0             NULL
May    0            0         0             NULL
Jun    0            0         0             NULL
Jul    0            0         0             NULL
Aug    0            0         0             NULL
Aug    2            200       2000          Unilever
Aug    1            100       1200          Unilever
Sep    0            0         0             NULL
Oct    0            0         0             NULL
Nov    0            0         0             NULL
Dec    0            0         0             NULL
```

I want this result

```
Month  Total_Order  Quantity  Total_Amount  Supplier
Jan    0            0         0             NULL
Feb    0            0         0             NULL
Mar    0            0         0             NULL
Apr    0            0         0             NULL
May    0            0         0             NULL
Jun    0            0         0             NULL
Jul    0            0         0             NULL
Aug    3            300       32000         Unilever
Sep    0            0         0             NULL
Oct    0            0         0             NULL
Nov    0            0         0             NULL
Dec    0            0         0             NULL
```

Comment: Your query looks like it should produce the desired result - my guess is that not all unilevers are the same (despite looking so) check for non printing characters and white spaces.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` does not match the query. In your selected columns you fetch totals for each month/supplier, but you are grouping by the `supplier_medicine_id`.

Not sure what you want the `GROUP BY` to be. What if there are multiple suppliers for a month? Do you want to show them as separate rows or summed up together?

As a rule of thumb: If you mix aggregate functions with non-aggregate columns the `GROUP BY` uses all non-aggregate columns. In your case you have non-aggregate columns:

- `DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%b')`
- `tbl_supplier.supplier_name`

So, your group by should be:

`GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tbl_date.date, '%b'), tbl_supplier.supplier_name`

If on the other hand you wish to have only one row per month, you need to prepare for the fact that multiple suppliers can appear on same month. In that case you can use `GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_supplier.supplier_name) AS Supplier`